# PHP Mail cant send it over url

Tags: php, email

I try to send an email with php. It works fine if i start the script over the console with: php mail.php" but if i try to call the script over the browser `http://localhost/mail.php` it dont works.

```
<?php
$sender = "test@mydomain.com";
$empfaenger = "me@mydomain.com";
$betreff = "Testmail";
$mailtext = "Test";
if(mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $mailtext, "From: $sender")) {
 echo "works";
} else {
 echo "dont";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why "@mail"? Shouldn't it be just "if(mail(...)) {"?  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: tried it, same result. owner of the file is wwwrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending mail on localhost from php doesn't work in the regular fashion. Follow **[this link](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html)** to see how you can simulate a mailserver on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect to a host mail with IMAP and send emails in localhost

see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Answer (score 0):

if you run url then mail is not sent because mail function is working only on live server.

if you want send mail in local then you need to connect with smtp.

after connect smtop when you run local url then mail is sent